# DTO property attributes

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm connecting to a service using [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net) that I have no control on:

I have a DTO like:

```
public class Request
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

But the service is expecting a request like `{"Property 1":"value"}` note the space between the word Property and the 1.  **Is there an attribute that I can use to set the name to the property that gets transmitted to the server?**  Something like the following would be helpful:

```
public class Request
{
    [Name("Property 1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using [DataContract] on your DTO class and [DataMember] for your properties? If so you can use the name property of the DataMember attribute.

Comment: Yes, I just found that this was adding in Pull Request #51, I am about to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pull Request #51 Added the following](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/51) as a result of [this issue request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues/41).

```
[DataContract]
public class Request
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Property 1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Attribute DataContract should be used in tandem with the property attributes DataMember. If you only use attribute DataContract on your DTO class then all properties will be ignored on a DTO call.